# How do I convert a comma-separated string into an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, csv

Is there any way to convert a comma separated string into an array in Ruby? For instance, if I had a string like this:

```
"one,two,three,four"
```

How would I convert it into an array like this?

```
["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

Comment: Why is there the "csv" tag? This isn't operating on `.csv` files, just a string separated with commas.

Comment: CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. That's what your string is. It's a pretty standard way of storing serial or tabular data in string format. It doesn't necessarily need to be read directly from a file.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: Ah, ok, I just thought that CSV was *just* the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Use the `split` method to do it:

```
"one,two,three,four".split(',')
# ["one","two","three","four"]
```

If you want to ignore leading / trailing whitespace use:

```
"one , two , three , four".split(/\s*,\s*/)
# ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

If you want to parse multiple lines (i.e. a CSV file) into separate arrays:

```
require "csv"
CSV.parse("one,two\nthree,four")
# [["one","two"],["three","four"]]
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent function to PHP's `str_getcsv` that will automatically handle quoted CSVs, values which include (escaped) commas, multiline CSVs, etc.?

Comment: @Lèse majesté: Yes, see my answer.

Comment: What about "one, two, three, four" - is there a quick way to trim the space?

Comment: @vanboom `"one, two, three, four".split(/\s*,\s*/)`. Split will work with a regular expression also. Alternatively you could use the `map` method if you prefer this syntax: `"one, two, three, four".split(',').map(&:strip)`

Answer (score 18):

```
require 'csv'
CSV.parse_line('one,two,three,four') #=> ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

Comment: This will return `nil` for empty elements `CSV.parse_line("one,two,,four") #=> ["one", "two", nil, "four"]`

Answer (score 10):

```
>> "one,two,three,four".split ","
=> ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your string has an unknown number of whitespaces before/after in *any* order/number, then you can also do the following:

```rb
'  one  ,   two,three, four   '.split(',').map { | item | item.strip }

#=> ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Wrote a [blog post](https://designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-convert-a-comma-separated-string-to-an-array-in-ruby) for those who're interested.