# Split string and append single quotes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, split

**Front End Request**
?date_filter=2019-03-12,2019-03-13

As you see, I am passing two dates in request from front end to ruby controller.

I want to convert those dates into below format so that I can use them in my SQL query

**Expected Result:**
['2019-03-12', '2019-03-13']

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Updated my question @bitsapien

Answer (score 1):

First get the query string data, then do the `split` on it, it will result an array of the values.

```
dates = request.query_parameters['date_filter']
result = dates.split(',')
```

result would be `['2019-03-12', '2019-03-13']`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847499/how-do-i-convert-a-comma-separated-string-into-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Let a be the query parameter you get the to get the required result use

```
a = "2019-03-12,2019-03-13"
a.split(",") //gives ["2019-03-12", "2019-03-12"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847499/how-do-i-convert-a-comma-separated-string-into-an-array

Comment: @KrunalShah Glad that you figured it out..! Good luck